# Error en PHP, constante T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Tags: php, array, sqlite

**Código PHP - SQLITE**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
// base de datos donde tomar los datos
$db_from = new dbProd();
// base de datos para insertar datos de la otra base de datoss
$db_to = new dbEncuestas();
// Con los datos o no
// $data = true;
if(!$db){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
}else {
    $stat = "Connected";
    if(!$db){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    }else {
        $stat2 = "Connected";

        // Leer datos de tabla tickets de db_from
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE closed_at > (select date ("now"))';

        $result = $db_from->query($sql);

        $filas_registros = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
           $filas_registros[] = current($row);
        }

        $tickets='tickets';

           echo "Comienza la migracion de datos \n";
           foreach ($db_to.$tickets as $db_from.$tickets){
              $sql = "INSERT INTO $db_to.tickets SELECT * FROM $db_from.tickets";
              $result = $db_to->query($sql);

           }
           echo "Termina la migracion de datos \n";

        $db_from->close();
        $db_to->close();
    }
}
?>
```

---

**Clases**

```
  <?php
  class dbEncuestas extends SQLite3
  {
      function __construct()
      {
          $this->open('../db/spiceworks_encuestas.db');
      }
  }
  class dbProd extends SQLite3
  {
      function __construct()
      {
          $this->open('../db/spiceworks_prod.db');
      }
  }
?>
```

---

**ERROR**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ::
>   (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\PruebasPasarDatos.php
>   on line 34

Comment: Este error es el operador de dos puntos `::` ver [analizador de lista de tokens](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) y también a veces esta es la forma de `PHP` para decirle que le falta un signo `$`... por ejemplo, si escribe `_SESSION ["foo"]` en lugar de `$ _SESSION ["foo"]`

Comment: Bienvenido @Hafid Morales Sànchez puedes explicar mas tu pregunta algunos detalles mas para ayudarte

Comment: Hola Hafid, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio). El error es porque estás poniendo un `.` donde PHP espera un `::`, pero para poder ayudarte mejor, ¿podrías compartir el código de las clases `dbProd` y `dbEncuestas`? ¿Qué es `$tickets`?

Comment: `tickets` es una tabla de db_from